# Internal server error when creating groups hold

Tags: google-vault-api

I'm getting the following error when performing a `matters.holds.create` call.

The body is:

```
{
  "corpus": "GROUPS",
  "accounts": [
    {
      "accountId": "account_id"
    }
  ],
  "name": "my name"
}
```

The error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
```

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Could you please provide the code you are using to generate this? Or at least the whole request you are using? A 500 error is weird maybe you are triggering an API Bug for a specific case.

Comment: I'm doing it via the google developer web UI.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your error, Could you provide more information on your setup? I'm trying and everything seems to work fine. When you say "Google Developer Web UI" do you mean the `Try it` button in [this page](https://developers.google.com/vault/reference/rest/v1/matters.holds/create)?

Comment: Yep, it's this page. Other corpus such as DRIVE and MAIL are working normally. I'm using these calls with a new user I created for testing.